# Drinfeld's Invariant Locus of Formal Scheme

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry

I am reading Drinfeld's *Elliptic Modules* paper. In the proof of Proposition 5.4, which is on the deformation of Drinfeld modules, he defines an action of a certain group $A_x^{\ast}$ on the functors of deformations of formal modules and Drinfeld modules.

In Drinfeld's notations, we let $F_0$ denote the ring representing the deformation functor of a Drinfeld $A$-module $X$ over $\overline{\mathbf{F}}_p$, and let $F_0^{'}$ be the ring representing the deformation functor of the same object $X$ but viewed as a Drinfeld $\mathbf{F}_p[x]$-module, where $A=\Gamma(X-\{\infty\},\mathcal{O}_X)$ is the ring of integers in a global function field.

Then with an appropriate action of $A_x^{\ast}$ defined, Drinfeld says $$(\operatorname{Spf}F_0^{'})^{A_x^{\ast}}=\operatorname{Spf}F_0$$But what is exactly this $(\operatorname{Spf}F_0^{'})^{A_x^{\ast}}$? My understanding is that it should be the "invariant locus" of the formal scheme $\operatorname{Spf}F_0^{'}$. Is this correct? Also, on the level of rings, how does one get $F_0$ from $F_0^{'}$ and the action of $A_x^{\ast}$?